# H2 DB path for automatic sript DML and DDL commands in the url jdbc

Tags: java, database, h2

i've read in H2 tutorial that i can execute DDL or DML commands automatically when a client connects to a databas by this way:

```
  String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from '~/create.sql'\\;runscript from '~/init.sql'";
```

but i can't understand how should i specify my path instead '~/create.sql'considering that i use maven sructure in my project and my sql script is located in the

```
 \src\test\resources\creationTables.sql
```